# Cannot get the value of the field?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the values inserted in text boxes from a Windows Form Application in excel.I tried To instantiate the class,I also tried to put the values in the constructor,I also tried to use

```
rvalue.Value2 = (decimal)a.SumaDepusa;
```

and also to make the SumaDepusa field Static which didn't worked.I get the same error for SumaDepusa:'Form1' does not contain a definition for 'SumaDepusa' and no accessible extension method 'SumaDepusa' accepting a first argument of type 'Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
This is the whole code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1 {

public partial class Form1 : Form {

    public Form1 () {

        InitializeComponent ();

    }

    public void textBox1_TextChanged (object sender, EventArgs e) {
        decimal SumaDepusa = decimal.Parse (textBox1.Text);
    }

    public class SumaFinala {

        public void Open () {
            try {
                Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application ();
                app.Visible = true;
                Form1 a = new Form1 ();
                Excel.Workbook wkb = app.Workbooks.Open (@"C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\a.xlsx");
                Excel.Range rvalue = app.get_Range ("A2");
                rvalue.Value2 = a.SumaDepusa;

            } catch (Exception e) {

                MessageBox.Show ("Eroare: " + e);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: There is no such field, as the error says. You only have a local variable inside a method. It won’t be visible outside.

Comment: I see much wrong with this code. First, I don't understand why you have those nested classes. Second, why are you creating a new instance of `Form1`? Third, the `SumaDepusa` field/property doesn't exist at form level, it's privately scoped inside the `textBox1_TextChanged` event. Honestly, I think you would benefit from a C# tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks very confusing to me and I do not know what you are trying to achieve.

Here is what I think you are trying to do.
I have implemented a class that grabs the value from the text box and upon clicking a button runs the `Open()` method. This method creates a sheet and inserts the value into "A[row]"

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public decimal SumaDepusa;
        public Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
        public int row = 1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var app = new Excel.Application
            {
                Visible = true
            };

            app.Workbooks.Add();
            worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)app.ActiveSheet;
        }

        public void Open()
        {
            try
            {
                if (decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out var decimalParsed))
                {
                    SumaDepusa = decimalParsed;
                    worksheet.Cells[row, "A"] = SumaDepusa;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Cannot parse: {textBox1.Text}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                MessageBox.Show($"Error: {e}");

            }
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Open();
            row++;
        }
    }
}
```

This method does open an excel sheet when the program runs so you would need to find a way to write to an excel sheet if it exists, if not create a new one. There will be other logic needed to make this work better. But for examples sake of getting the value its this.